# JSF no instancia un ManagedBean

Tags: java, spring, jsf, primefaces, spring-boot

estoy desarrollando una aplicación web con SpringBoot-JSF-Primefaces, y me he encontrado con que los controladores, que utilizo como @ManagedBean(el de JSF, he comprobado que no sea javax annotation) no se llegan a instanciar, y por tanto no puedo acceder a ellos desde la vista.

Aquí está mi faces-config.xml (está bajo WEB-INF)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
              version="2.2">
    <application>
       <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver
 </application>
</faces-config>
```

Y aquí mi web.xml (también bajo ese directorio)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" version="3.1">
   <description>web.xml para la aplicacion tfg</description>
   <display-name>TFG</display-name>
   <welcome-file-list>
     <welcome-file>inicio.xhtml</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>
   
   <listener>
     <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
   </listener>
   <listener>
     <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
   </listener>

   
   <servlet>
     <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
   
   <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Y aquí mi aplicación de arranque:

```js
import javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
    
    @Override
 protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
  return application.sources(new Class[] { Application.class});
 }
    
    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean<FacesServlet> servletRegistrationBean() {
        FacesServlet servlet = new FacesServlet();
        return new ServletRegistrationBean<FacesServlet>(servlet, "*.xhtml");
    }
    
}
```

Os suplico que me ayudéis. Si utilizo el ManagedBean de javax.annotation me funciona, pero no me deja utilizar FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), y lo necesito.

Muchisimas gracias de antemano

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. ¿Te sale algo en el log? Y ¿podrías poner un ejemplo de como está definido el bean (no necesariamente todo, un bean con una sola propiedad nos dará una idea)?

Comment: Si, falta el código del ManagedBean es necesario saber que scope usas. También sería muy bueno saber que versiones de Spring, JSF y de PrimeFaces utilizais.